# Finding Uniform Convergence of the series of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Test for the uniform convergence of the series
$$\sum \frac{nx}{1+(nx)^2}$$
$x$ belongs to $\Bbb{R}$ and $n$ varies from 1 to $\infty$.
I tried to find the maximum value of the given function for applying Weierstrass' test but I got max value as $0.5$ so I can't use this test. Please help me.

Comment: What is the interval on which $x$ varies?

Comment: x belongs to entire R

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ may be any element of $\mathbb{R}$ then there isn't pointwise convergence, let alone uniform convergence. For example if $x=1$ the series becomes:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{1+n^2}$$ which diverges.

Comment: thanks. can you suggest any other method?

Answer (score 1):

There is a harder way:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{1+(nx)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\frac{1}{n}+nx^2}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{x}{\frac{1}{n}+nx^2}=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\text{H}_{m-\frac{i}{x}}+\text{H}_{m+\frac{i}{x}}-\text{H}_{-\frac{i}{x}}-\text{H}_{\frac{i}{x}}}{2x}=\frac{1}{2x}\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\text{H}_{m-\frac{i}{x}}+\text{H}_{m+\frac{i}{x}}-\text{H}_{-\frac{i}{x}}-\text{H}_{\frac{i}{x}}\right)$$

With $\text{H}_n$ is the nth harmonic number.

---

You've to show that (and it is!):

When $m\to\infty$ than $\text{H}_{m-\frac{i}{x}}+\text{H}_{m+\frac{i}{x}}-\text{H}_{-\frac{i}{x}}-\text{H}_{\frac{i}{x}}\to\infty$